# L'ajout du « e » quand on passe de "cum" à "comme", que signifie-t-il ?

Tags: étymologie, latin, ancien-français

J'ai lu, mais je ne cite pas, [le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/comme) car il m'apparaît confus. Je cite [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/comme) :

> (842, *Serments de Strasbourg*) cum ; com en ancien français, puis *comme*, **avec l'adjonction de *e* (= *et*)**.
>   Du latin populaire **quōmo*, altération
>   du latin classique [*quōmŏdo*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quomodo), « comment, de quelle façon » (de *quō*, ablatif de *quĭs*, « quel » et *mŏdo*, ablatif de *mŏdus*, « façon »).

1. Pourquoi *e* (= *et*) a-t-il ajouté (si on sait) ?
2. L'ajout de *e* (= *et*), que contribue-t-il sémantiquement à « comme » ?

Comment: Comme ça, je ne vois aucun mot où on prononce la dernière lettre si c'est une consonne... Et je prononcerai donc "com" de la même manière que "con"...

Comment: @Random En faiT c'est assez courant pour des mots d'une syllabe, dE prononcer des lettres finales qui sont d'habitude muettes, et pas quE dans le suD. Les seuls exemples qui mE viennent à l'esprit en -M ou -N sont des mots importés ou des onomatopées, mais ce ne serait pas si surprenant quE ça.

Comment: @Gilles j'accepte "FaiT" et "Sud", mais "quE" et "mE" finisent par une voyelle, donc normal... :p

Comment: @Random La lettr(e) E est muett(e) en final(e) d'habitud(e).

Comment: iL est claiR et neT, breF c'est un faiT, que sans être un aS on trouve des exemples. Un ami ami roM (3eme daN) m'a parlé du foehN mais on pourrait me rétorquer que ce sont des mots importés du SuD, de l'EsT ou de l'OuesT. Allons donC derecheF boire un raB de giN pour oublier ça.

Comment: @Random On ne peut pas appliquer nos règles de prononciations actuelles, pour définir comment un mot latin a fait pour se transformer en mot français.

Comment: Le TLFi renvoie à [Quint. _Inst._ 8 I.2](https://archive.org/stream/institutioorator03quinuoft#page/196/mode/2up) pour le _quomodo et_.

Answer (score 3):

> Pourquoi e (= et) a-t-il ajouté (si on sait) ?

Ce **e** provient de la conjonction de coordination latine ***et*** qui était ajouté à ***quomodo*** dans les conjonctions comparatives.

> L'ajout de e (= et), que contribue-t-il sémantiquement à « comme » ?

Oui.

---

En ancien français, on rencontre plusieurs graphies pour le mot ayant évolué vers le mot **comme** contemporain, les plus courantes étant :

- ***com***
- ***come***
- ***cum*** (parfois par confusion avec l'homonyme latin ***cum*** (=avec) dont « comme » ne dérive pas)

De là vient la représentation souvent rencontrée dans les ouvrages étymologiques :

- ***com(e)***

L'origine de ce mot est le latin ***quomodo*** qui vient de ***quo modo*** et signifie « de quel mode / de quelle manière ».

***Com*** n'était pas prononcé [**kɔm**] comme on le ferait aujourd'hui, mais [**kõm**]. Il comportait une nasalisation.

La variante avec un e final provient du latin ***quomodo et***. Il s'agit alors d'une conjonction comparative signifiant « de même que / de la même façon que ».

Le e final n'étant pas muet, ***come*** était dissyllabique et donc prononcé « comé » à la manière de l'italien *come* [**kome**].

---

Références:

[Olivier, Cl. (1985), « L’art et la manière : comment dans les stratégies discursives », De l’énonciation au lexique, Anscombre, J.-Cl. (dir.), Langages, vol. 20, n° 80, pp. 71-98.](http://www.persee.fr/doc/lgge_0458-726x_1985_num_20_80_1514)

> *quomodo* a fait bloc avec des adverbes tels *sic, ita, et*, pour prendre une valeur comparative.
>
> le morphème *quomodo*, à l’origine spécialisé dans l’interrogation sur la manière, en est venu progressivement à assurer, seul ou en composition, de nombreux emplois (…) de que, comme et comment du français moderne. Cette polyvalence est sans doute à mettre en relation avec le sémantisme de base qu- qui tend à neutraliser les spécifications apportées par les compositions et les figements. En ancien et moyen français *com/cum* et *come* (< *quomodo et*) recouvrent de façon assez indistincte tous les emplois (entre autres) des anciennes formes *quomodo/quomodo et*. Cette situation a provoqué l’apparition de formations telles que : comment, comfaitement, comfaitierement, combien, pour éviter les confusions. [Olivier 1985 : 73]

---

Aslanov Cyril, « Comme / comment du latin au français : perspectives diachronique, comparatiste et typologique », Travaux de linguistique, 1/2009 (n° 58), p. 19-38.

https://www.cairn.info/revue-travaux-de-linguistique-2009-1-page-19.htm

> Du point de vue diachronique, l’évolution qui a conduit au remplacement de *com* par *comment* doit être mise en relation avec le remplacement progressif de com [kõm] monosyllabe au moyen de [kome] dissyllabe. Du reste, *com* et *come* ont coexisté pendant un certain temps en ancien français. Curieusement l’amuïssement du –e caduc à la fin du XVIe siècle a rendu *comme* en tout point semblable à *com* monosyllabique qu’il avait fini par supplanter au cours du passage de l’ancien au moyen français.

...

> Remarquons que la volonté d’éviter une collision homonymique avec les avatars de la préposition cum (> con), qui paraît avoir été à l’œuvre dans le remplacement de *como* par *come* (< *quomodo et*) en domaine italo-roman, ne semble pas avoir été pertinente en ancien français, puisque aussi bien la préposition cum n’a pas eu de continuation en domaine gallo-roman.

---